# Send mail by php mail() function

Tags: php, html, email

I have problem with sending mail message by php *mail()* function. I'm not sure if it's problem with code coz I have read that some hosting servers are not allowing to sends mail but I'm trying to send this mail also when website is on localhost and it still doesn't work - after click "Send" I see the information: "Your mail is sent", but when I'm checking on my postbox there is no mails (also in spam).

For me code looks good but maybe I'm missing something. The second option which I'm considering is that also my localhost is not allowing to send mails.

```
<form id="contact" action="mail.php" method="POST">
    <div class="field">
        <label class="fixed_width" for="name">Name:</label><input id="name" name="name" value="Name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label class="fixed_width" for="surname">Surname:</label><input id="surname" name="surname" value="Surname"/>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label class="fixed_width" for="mail">E-mail:</label><input id="mail" name="mail" value="E-mail"/>
    </div>
    <div class="field" id="message">
        <label class="fixed_width" id="message_width" for="mail">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" />Type your message...</textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="width" type="submit" value="Send" />
    </div>
</form>

<?php

    srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
    $marker = md5(uniqid(rand()));

    $receiver  = "address@gmail.com";
    $title = "Mail";
    $sender  = $_POST['name'];
    $sender .= $_POST['surname'];
    $sender_mail = $_POST['mail'];

    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $headers  = "From: $sender <$sender_mail>\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n";
    $headers .= "\tboundary=\"___$marker==\"";

    $content ="--___$marker==\n";
    $content .="Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-2\"\n";
    $content .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
    $content .="\n$message\n";

    if (mail($receiver,$title,$content,$headers))
    {
        print "Your message is sent.";
    } else {
        print "Your message is not sent.
        <br>Please go <a href=\"javascript:history.back();\">back</a> and send again.";
    }
?>
```

Pictures with my php conf:

[image: PHP config]
[image: PHP config]
[image: PHP config]

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on?  Have you tried a different e-mail than gmail?  Is there a reason you are using boundaries (not necessary)? You don't appear to have an "-f" parameter, which helps deliverability...

Comment: If I were you, I'd change the 'value' attributes of your inputs to 'placeholder'. This will save you having to rely on JS to check if those fields have their values set to defaults and, if so, clearing them when they receive focus and setting them when they're empty on blur. Seeing as you've already given labels to these fields, setting values is redundant. Additionally, I'd put strip_tags() or filter_var() calls around your $_POST variables. (Don't ever trust user input without some form of sanitation.)

Comment: @cale_b OP has specified that this is on localhost.

Comment: I've never had luck sending e-mails from a localhost install...

Comment: It's localhost, I have tried also on other e-mail than gmail.

Comment: I wonder if sendmail is installed or configured correctly on the server.

Comment: I also think that it can be problem with server but I don't know how to change it, above pictures with mym php conf:
http://imageshack.com/a/img842/6421/z7fr.png
http://imageshack.com/a/img842/4315/hjdv.png
http://imageshack.com/a/img46/9827/qgkw.png

Answer (score 8):

To test that sending of email works, try this really short program:

```
<?php
$email_to="address@gmail.com";
$email_subject="It works";
$email_message="Hello. I can send mail!";
$headers = "From: Beacze\r\n".
"Reply-To: address@gmail.com\r\n'" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
echo "mail sent!"
?>
```

I have used one "just like it" in the past as the starting point for testing a configuration. If this doesn't work it's most likely your server configuration.

Comment: The same situation. I'm getting information "mail sent!" but on my post box is no mails.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing you inbox? Sometimes it can take a while. Also, does the server you're sending through (eg, if using google's mail server) require authentication?

Comment: Yes, I have refreshed few times. No I hadn't any authentication.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SMTP (phpmailer)
Example:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->Host       = "mail.example.com"; // SMTP server example
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "username"; // SMTP account username example
$mail->Password   = "password";        // SMTP account password example
```

You can find more about PHPMailer here: https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

Comment: Hmm... I want to write only simple contact form, so I don't know from where I can take username and password.

Comment: The username and password are for the smtp mail server through which you send the emails, if the mail server requires authentication.