# How to send an official confirmation mail of confirming order from an app using the details provided by user in a e-commerce app.

Tags: android, email, e-commerce

I am developing an android app for an E-commerce website. I am a newbie in this field. I want to implement cash on delivery option in the app. I am taking the details of the user like name, email,shipping address in the app. After placing order I want to send a confirmation mail to the email id  provided by user from my official email of the company. Please guide me with the code,how can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the backend framework you are using? Assuming that you need to send the mail from some server you are maintaining?

Comment: the website is using PHP backend.

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Check this stackoverflow question too.
[Send mail by php mail() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961821/send-mail-by-php-mail-function)